# Is 'stakehold' (used as a noun) an acceptable word, even though no major dictionary lists it?

Tags: word-usage

I fear this question may turn out to be off-topic, because it may come down to personal opinion. If so, my apologies, although I'd be interested to hear the opinions of members of this community.

On the one hand, no major dictionary lists *stakehold* as a word. This includes:

1. *OED*; 2. *[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stakehold)*; 3. *[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/stakehold)* (autocorrects to *stakeholding*); 4. *[American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stakehold);* 5. *[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english?q=stakehold);* 6. *[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/american/?q=stakehold);* 7. *[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=stakehold);* 8. *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=stakehold&title=Special:Search&go=Go&searchToken=guh8ptks8o4eweq91r8wjpa1);* 9. *[Webster's New World College Dictionary, 4th ed.](http://www.yourdictionary.com/search/results/?q=stakehold?direct_search_result=yes)* (the site searches that dictionary, as can be seen e.g. [here](http://www.yourdictionary.com/stakeholder)); 10. *[Wordsmyth](https://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=stakehold);* 11. *[Webster's Revised Unabridged, 1913 ed.](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Stakehold);* 12. *[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=stakehold&s=t);* 13. *[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/stakehold);* 14. *[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/Stakehold);* 15. *[Infoplease](https://www.infoplease.com/dictionary/stakehold);* 16. *[OPTED](http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~ralph/OPTED/v003/wb1913_s.html);* and 17. *[Free Dictionary](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=stakehold).*

On the other hand, a search in *google books* shows that *stakehold*, used as a noun, does appear in published literature. The number and context of its appearances is such that, to me, it seems unlikely that all of these appearances are mistakes. In other words, it seems to me that, in many cases, the word was used purposefully by very literate writers. Some examples:

1. *taking a **stakehold** in its future* [(here)](https://books.google.com/books?id=L_ttS6iZpOEC&lpg=PA75&dq=%22a%20stakehold%22&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q=%22a%20stakehold%22&f=false);
2. *interested parties should have a **stakehold** in conservation* [(here)](https://books.google.com/books?id=MvF1iDnIaaMC&lpg=PA14&dq=%22a%20stakehold%22&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=%22should%20have%20a%22&f=false);
3. *a **stakehold** interest in education* ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=qDwihZo3_qwC&lpg=PA13&dq=%22a%20stakehold%22&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q=%22interest%20in%20education%22&f=false), though in this case it is possibly an adjective);
4. *a **stakehold** he shared with several other miners* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=3EyRW4D7KpL8tAXwi7NA&q=%22he+shared+with+several+other+miners+and+metallurgists%22&oq=%22he+shared+with+several+other+miners+and+metallurgists%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6787.6787.0.7132.1.1.0.0.0.0.110.110.0j1.1.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.4mdlf3pvq1M);
5. *the money was accordingly deposited in the hands of the defendant, as a **stakehold*** [(here)](https://books.google.com/books?id=kwtHAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22a%20stakehold%22&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q=%22a%20stakehold%22&f=false);
6. *the whole idea is for us to get a **stakehold** in a significant number of small businesses* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=u02RW9GcL4Ob8wWyobqoBA&q=%22unit+the+whole+idea+is+for+us+to+get+a%22&oq=%22unit+the+whole+idea+is+for+us+to+get+a%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10281.10967.0.11518.5.5.0.0.0.0.304.304.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.h58tJn-TsKc);
7. *we will have people who have a **stakehold** in this Country* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=1U6RW5GbDImi8QXy4r_wBQ&q=%22all+around+this+country.+We+will+have+people+who+have+a%22&oq=%22all+around+this+country.+We+will+have+people+who+have+a%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...30198.48558.0.54333.55.39.0.0.0.0.462.5944.2-12j3j4.19.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..43.0.0....0.oz3gGqrUTvY);
8. *everybody in Mississippi knew it was a **stakehold** of beatniks and immorality.* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=TU-RW8HEHIOX8wWs_p2wCg&q=%22I+complained+about+them+operati+out+of+there.+Everybody+in+Mississippi+knew+it+was+a%22&oq=%22I+complained+about+them+operati+out+of+there.+Everybody+in+Mississippi+knew+it+was+a%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...22871.22871.0.24875.1.1.0.0.0.0.287.287.2-1.1.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.GAYzwkhGl_8);
9. *to insure that K-12 education has a **stakehold** in the development... of the NREN* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22Its+principal+goal+is+to+insure+that+K-12+education+has%22);
10. *Maryam also acquired a **stakehold** of 60 per cent shares* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=rlCRW5DXGO7H_QaW046IDw&q=%22of+60+per+cent+shares+worth+%2420%2C058+million%22&oq=%22of+60+per+cent+shares+worth+%2420%2C058+million%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9874.9874.0.10373.1.1.0.0.0.0.132.132.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.28TLJteFKX0);
11. *to acquire a **stakehold** in a Japanese company* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=uVCRW_HFGInm_QaKoI3gCg&q=%22+in+a+Japanese+company+than+it+is+in+a+US+company+because%22&oq=%22+in+a+Japanese+company+than+it+is+in+a+US+company+because%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...114103.114103.0.114528.1.1.0.0.0.0.119.119.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.kDG4Q7yjbiY);
12. *to compensate employees with a **stakehold** in the company* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22+a+combination+that+motivated+the+large+public+companies+to+use+either+401%28k%29+plans+to+compensate+employees+with%22);
13. *fortunately for those who have a **stakehold** in the Association* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=GVCRW87LFIib_Qb30ZrwDg&q=%22And+fortunately+for+those+who+have+a+stakehold+in+the+Association%22&oq=%22And+fortunately+for+those+who+have+a+stakehold+in+the+Association%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...444767.445429.0.445735.3.3.0.0.0.0.132.382.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.0-BMRyqMWnI);
14. *we are poised to have a **stakehold** in the PC market* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=ZVKRW9bmPJD4_AbQyoa4DQ&q=%22Namco+believes+that+as+a+strong+publisher+with+a+great+management+team+and+production+history%2C+we+are+poised+to+have%22&oq=%22Namco+believes+that+as+a+strong+publisher+with+a+great+management+team+and+production+history%2C+we+are+poised+to+have%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12360.12360.0.13042.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.ROtLUK86spA);
15. *they had a **stakehold** in it* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22because+of+their+insurance+cross-ownership+and+operations.+They+had%22);
16. *those who had attained a **stakehold** in the state* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=GFORW4uiJeaZ_QaY_aCIBQ&q=%22in+the+state%2C+namely+day+labourers%2C+poor+husbandmen%2C+yea+merchants+or+retailers+which+have+no%22&oq=%22in+the+state%2C+namely+day+labourers%2C+poor+husbandmen%2C+yea+merchants+or+retailers+which+have+no%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...16220.18987.0.19391.2.2.0.0.0.0.205.324.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.V2W5c5lzNns);
17. *recognition of a **stakehold** interest in the property* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=LFORW-WJKrKJggfQx7TICw&q=%22ensuring+adherence+to+the+rules+and+when+they+carry+with+them+no+recognition+of%22&oq=%22ensuring+adherence+to+the+rules+and+when+they+carry+with+them+no+recognition+of%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...80891.80891.0.81330.1.1.0.0.0.0.129.129.0j1.1.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.V4L1UBp8t-U);
18. *provide a **stakehold** in the assessment process* ([here](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=vlORW9fmCM7p_QbwiJXgCg&q=%22it+is+possible+to+forge+a+relationship+with+the+family+that+will+maximize+cooperation+and+provide%22&oq=%22it+is+possible+to+forge+a+relationship+with+the+family+that+will+maximize+cooperation+and+provide%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5299.5299.0.5502.1.1.0.0.0.0.108.108.0j1.1.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.kvVScWfC80Y). This is from the 2009 ed.; interestingly, as one can see in the link, *stakehold* was changed to *stake* in the 2010 ed.);
19. *something to have a **stakehold** in if you own a big corporation* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22Is+that+what+our+children+have+become%2C+something+to+have%22);
20. *as a **stakehold** against depreciation* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=i1WRW76JPMmxggfM3pvoCg&q=%22Holders+of+foreign+funds+want+to+cache+them+in+the+United+States+%28a%29+as%22&oq=%22Holders+of+foreign+funds+want+to+cache+them+in+the+United+States+%28a%29+as%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...122389.122389.0.122886.1.1.0.0.0.0.129.129.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.o_PbT3dC5eo);
21. *5% of the value of the **stakehold*** [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=yVaRW7vHEKnv_Qb9ma2ADw&q=%22+but+in+no+event+less+than+_+%24300.00+For+representing%22&oq=%22+but+in+no+event+less+than+_+%24300.00+For+representing%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15643.15643.0.16200.1.1.0.0.0.0.120.120.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.KbtT5fnAokA);
22. *the **stakehold** was held liable for paying over* [(here)](https://books.google.com/books?id=_nguAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22the%20stakehold%22&pg=PA597#v=onepage&q=%22the%20stakehold%22&f=false);
23. *belts and chains for sending men up from the **stakehold**, or down from aloft* [(here)](https://books.google.com/books?id=OtUDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA190&dq=%22the+stakehold%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9gPDw5qbdAhXxT98KHTnBA6wQ6AEIXDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20stakehold%22&f=false);
24. *a collective entitlement known as a **"stakehold"*** [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=3VaRW-KLFfKGggejta3QCg&q=%22the+past+has+grown+into+a+collective+entitlement+known+as%22&oq=%22the+past+has+grown+into+a+collective+entitlement+known+as%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...251989.251989.0.253294.1.1.0.0.0.0.291.291.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.DPG4259NSBw);
25. *upriver from it was Cambridge-on-Jordan, the **stakehold** of the chief legist* [(here)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22The+plateau+behind+Mount+Garben+was+simply+called+Landing%2C+but+upriver+from+it+was+Cambridge-on-Jordan%22);

In most cases above, one could replace *stakehold* by the dictionary-listed word *stake* (see esp. 18.). But in other cases, e.g. 23, the word means something different.

So, my question: should the usage of *stakehold* as a noun be considered acceptable in (a) formal writing? (b) informal writing and speech?

Obviously, this is a special case of a more general question of [just how widespread should a word become before it becomes acceptable](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/02/08/when-does-wrong-become-right/). This general question is likely impossible to answer; nevertheless, the particular case at hand might be more tractable.

**EDIT**

One type of usage that seems particularly prevalent is *to have a **stakehold** in something.*

True, the writers/speakers could (should?) have simply said *to have a **stake** in something.* True, none of the dictionaries recognize *stakehold* in this meaning. True, its etymology is probably that of a faulty back-formation, or a malapropism, or some other kind of mistake. But none of these considerations come anywhere near to being decisive arguments against something being a 'legitimate' word. Many now-legitimate words started off as isolated mistakes. But gradually, perhaps because it was a natural mistake to make, their usage spread, and eventually the dictinaries 'recognized' them as legitimate. But remember that, in English, the inclusion of a word in the dictionaries is not what makes a word legitimate. It is the other way around: it is because the word has become widespread enough and accepted by enough speakers as legitimate that the dictionaries finally begin to include it. So for every new word, there is a span of time during which it is a legitimate word even though the dictionaries haven't included it yet. (Of course, *being a legitimate word* is a vague concept; a word can be more or less legitimate.) One way to phrase my question is whether *to have a **stakehold** in something* is in this intermediate stage: widely accepted and 'legitimate', but not yet recognized by dictionaries as such.

You can also think of my question this way: if you think that the phrase *to have a **stakehold** in something* does not belong to Standard English, how prevalent would it have to become for you to change your mind? What would it take, what's the threshold?

Here are more examples, from all walks of life and both sides of the Atlantic:

1. *Even if a better writer were to appear — one who, unlike Knopper, appreciated Jackson’s artistry and desired understanding more than a **stakehold** in a profitable mythology — a “definitive” biography would still be impossible.*
   <sup>[*Los Angeles Review of Books*](https://lareviewofbooks.org/article/time-for-something-different/)</sup>
2. *So would giving people a **stakehold** in land and corporate ownership.*
   <sup>[*Society in Focus: An Introduction to Sociology*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EWN0DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA233&dq=%22stakehold%20in%20land%20and%20corporate%20ownership.%20In%20developing%20countries%2C%20tax%20and%20transfer%20programs%20would%20provide%20some%20help%22&pg=PA233#v=onepage&q=%22stakehold%20in%20land%20and%20corporate%20ownership.%20In%20developing%20countries,%20tax%20and%20transfer%20programs%20would%20provide%20some%20help%22&f=false)</sup>
3. *It's aimed at those with a **stakehold** in disability: family, friends, professionals and, rather importantly, disabled people themselves.*
   <sup>[BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ouch/about.shtml)</sup>
4. *APSA is also proud to be part of the greater community of organizations with a **stakehold** in improving the lives of children.* 
   <sup>[The American Pediatric Surgical Association](https://eapsa.org/apsa-info/about-us/)</sup>
5. *…to ensure that every community feels that they have a **stakehold** in their government.* 
   <sup>[U.S. Rep. Ayanna Pressley (D-Mass.)](https://www.wbur.org/news/2018/12/29/mass-congress-new-years-resolutions)</sup>
6. *More than 150 people with a **stakehold** in the housing and construction industries came to the launch of Advance TECC.* 
   <sup>[Invest Waltham Forest](https://www.investwalthamforest.com/advanceTECC)</sup>
7. *This should be of urgent interest to anyone who has a **stakehold** in engaging all children in literacy.* 
   <sup>Fen Coles, co-director of Letterbox Library, in a [publication](https://clpe.org.uk/sites/default/files/News%20release%20-%20Reflecting%20Realities%20-%20new%20study%20calls%20for%20better%20ethnic%20representation%20in%20children%27s%20books_0.pdf) by the Centre for Literacy in Primary Education</sup>
8. *This has still brought positive interest in the City of London from a number of overseas buyers wanting a **stakehold** in what we believe is an ever-appealing investment zone.*

    <sup>Lesley Males, Head of Research at real estate research company Datscha, in [City A.M.](https://www.cityam.com/non-eu-investment-london-commercial-property-rose-75-per/)</sup>
9. *I’m talking about how your grandma, who may not be the best in the kitchen, finally has a **stakehold** in Thanksgiving and somehow leaves your stomach still growling afterwards.*

   <sup>[*Her Campus*](https://www.hercampus.com/school/u-del/eight-things-not-say-about-grandmas-thanksgiving-dinner) at University of Delware</sup>
10. *EasiBridge is looking for external investors to take a **stakehold** in driving the considerable product portfolio to market.*
    <sup>[GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/emerging-innovation-in-portable-user-friendly-bridging-technique)</sup>
11. *Being able to use this act to bring together the interested parties that had a **stakehold** in these canyons.*
    <sup>Steve Lentz, owner of Far and Away Adventures, in [*National Parks Traveler*](https://www.nationalparkstraveler.org/2018/03/wild-and-scenic-rivers-act-fifty)</sup>
12. *This mission-driven strategy is even more important in today’s market of expansive neighborhood gentrification where long-term residents with a **stakehold** in the community can be displaced.*
    <sup>Bill Whitman, Partner at Somerset Development Company, in [*citybizlist*](https://dc.citybizlist.com/article/543247/mac-realty-advisors-arranges-recapitalization-of-channel-square-apartments-in-southwest-dc)</sup>
13. *I’ve got a **stakehold** in those kids out there too.*
    <sup>Mickey Daughtry, retiring CFO of the Troy Board of Education, in [*troymessenger.com*](https://www.troymessenger.com/2019/09/17/troy-school-board-passes-budget-with-100k-surplus/)</sup>
14. *Anyone with a **stakehold** in the inquest can apply to be an ‘interested party’.*
    <sup>[Slater Gordon Lawyers](https://www.troymessenger.com/2019/09/17/troy-school-board-passes-budget-with-100k-surplus/)</sup>

Comment: Bear in mind that Wall Street guys speak terrible English. It's the type of mistake one would expect from them.

Comment: A very interesting article with ngrams that make sense:https://mikeclayton.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/the-origin-of-stakeholders/

Comment: The obvious point of comparison would be _sharehold_ as a noun, would it not?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that a stakeholder has a stake that they hold, hence the name :-)

Comment: This is like *orient* and *orientate*, or more recently, *crown* and *coronate*. It’s the voice of the lazy and ignorant, and (unfortunately) it seems to be getting louder.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because though many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. As you well know. As you say, in fact. // It _does_ nicely exemplify the wording grey area.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I understand your point re closure, but I think both the question and [@]MetaEd's answer are useful additions to our EL&U library. If a person looks for *stakehold* in a reputable dictionary, fails to find it and wonders why, where else would we encourage them to turn but here, to find the answer? I'm voting to leave it open.

Comment: @Chappo I'd actually prefer it to stay open myself, but want to signal that a flood of "Is 'snakehold' an acceptable word?" copycat questions are/is not on.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If there are other questionable words/phrases that are as well represented in reputable sources as *to have a stakehold in* is, probably they indeed all deserve to be on EL&U. It is not at all common to find a word/phrase that is well represented in all kinds of writing, including high-quality writing (by which I mean e.g. texbooks, literary reviews, articles in well-known edited newspapers and magazines, PR material of well-known organizations, etc.), and yet is not recorded in the dictionaries.

Comment: @linguisticum How on earth are we going to answer 'One way to phrase my question is whether to have a stakehold in something is in this intermediate stage: widely accepted and 'legitimate', but not yet recognized by dictionaries as such.' other than by merely echoing "Yes, you're right, it's a grey area' or voting for or against acceptability? We can't **_decide_** on wordness on ELU.

Answer (score 60):

In most cases where it is used, *stakehold* is an error. I see multiple explanations for this word showing up in the examples you found. A few might be intentional, but most are clearly mistakes of one kind or another.

1. As a back-formation from *stakeholder*, meaning essentially the same as *stake* in its sense of *interest* or *wager*. In this context, possibly also a malapropism for *share*.

   > *Maryam also acquired a *stakehold* of 60 per cent shares.
   >   Maryam also acquired a *stake* of 60 per cent shares.
   >   Maryam also acquired a *share* [or *shares*] of 60 per cent.

   [seems relevant to 1–5, 7, 9–13, 15, 17–22, 24]
2. As a malapropism from *foothold* when used figuratively in its sense of a secure position.

   > *We are poised to have a *stakehold* in the PC market.
   >   We are poised to have a *foothold* in the PC market.

   [seems relevant to 6, 14, 16, 20]
3. As a misspelling of *stokehold*, essentially a room deep within a steamship where coal is fed to the boiler.

   > *belts and chains for sending men up from the *stakehold*
   >   belts and chains for sending men up from the *stokehold*

   [seems relevant to 23]

I would expect a good copy-editor to correct these, with the possible exception of 24, which was apparently used deliberately and defined in context.

4. Your number 25 seems created for a literary purpose, meaning a *hold* (a shelter or keep) associated with a property claim (a *stake* in the sense used by prospectors), by analogy from words such as *household*, *stronghold*, and *freehold*.

Note that I do not mean to definitively impose an organizing system on your examples, just to show that they mostly arise from several kinds of confusion. It is certainly possible that some of your examples could fit in more than one category, or even that some were the result of several types of confusion all at once.

Comment: Great analysis that the uses in the OP are not all used to mean the same thing.  I'd add that for some of these I think the word "stake" alone might be sufficient.  Some seem to be saying "a firm hold in one's stake".  "As a stakehold against" sounds very natural to me but Google doesn't seem to recognize it, although "as a stake against" is apparently more common.

Comment: For meaning 1, another likely replacement word could be *holding* - e.g. "Maryam also acquired a holding of 60 per cent shares."

Comment: @TobySpeight That whole sentence doesn't make any sense. There's no such thing, as far as I know, as "60 per cent shares".  You could hold 60 per cent _of_ the shares of a company.

Comment: @Kevin 1/60 cent shares would certainly be cheap.

Comment: That bit I just copied without proofreading - sorry for not correcting it on the way, @Kevin.

Comment: @TobySpeight I wasn't criticizing you, just saying that you were trying to correct a garbage sentence to begin with.

Comment: @Kevin - You might also hold "a 60% share in the company".

Answer (score 28):

I suspect that ***stakehold*** is not a word because a *stakeholder* is one who *holds* a *stake* in something.  Oxford Living Dictionaries describes it thusly:

> ***[stakeholder](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stakeholder)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. (in gambling) an independent party with whom each of those who make a wager deposits the money or counters wagered.
> 2. A person with an interest or concern in something, especially a business.

Merriam-Webster says:

> Definition of ***[stakeholder](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stakeholder)***
>
> 1. a person entrusted with the stakes of bettors
> 2. one that has a stake in an enterprise
> 3. one who is involved in or affected by a course of action

So the noun is ***stake***, not ***stakehold***.

I will note that ***stakehold*** is *not* like the word ***foothold*** in that a *foot* holds onto a *foothold*; a stake (in this context) can't hold on to something but instead is being held.

> ***[foothold](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/foothold)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. A place where a person's foot can be lodged to support them securely, especially while climbing.
>
>    1.1 *[usually in singular]* A secure position from which further progress may be made.
>
>    *‘the company is attempting to gain a foothold in the Russian market’*

(from the Oxford Living Dictionaries)

Interestingly, it seems that ***stronghold*** does not follow the *foothold* pattern but instead comes from an archaic definition of *hold* as a noun:

> ***[hold](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hold)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 3. archaic A fortress.

(from the Oxford Living Dictionaries)

So ***stronghold*** seems to just be a beefed up version of a *hold*:

> ***[stronghold](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stronghold)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. A place that has been fortified so as to protect it against attack.
>
>    *‘their mountain strongholds fell to enemy attack’*
> 2. A place where a particular cause or belief is strongly defended or upheld.
>
>    *‘a Labour stronghold’*

(from the Oxford Living Dictionaries)

---

**Update:**

Although far from a definitive source, the website [Anagrammer.com says](https://www.anagrammer.com/crossword/answer/stakehold):

> *The answer **STAKEHOLD** has 0 possible clues in existing crosswords. The word **STAKEHOLD** is NOT valid in any word game. See additional results below.*

Comment: 1. So all 25 examples of usage I found are simply wrong? 2. What about the cases like 23, which do not seem to mean *stake*? (Also 4, 8, 22, 24, and 25?)

Comment: Errors occur all the time in print for many, many reasons.  Specifically...  #4 is a guide to a fantasy world so it's possible that _stakehold_ has a meaning in that world.  
#8 appears to be the transcription of testimony, so it seems possible that someone used _stakehold_ when they meant _stronghold_.  
#22 -- it seems clear the meaning is stakehold**er**  
#23 -- could be another mistake and the intended word was _stronghold_.

Comment: This is correct: stakes are acquired by stakeholder is a word; stakehold is not correct in modern parlance in finance and economics. Internet "stuff" has to be taken with many grains of salt. Some is ignorance and some is lack of editing. But, this answer is right on.

Comment: #24 appears to be cut off; I couldn't get to the full quote.  Given that _stakehold_ is preceded by a quote but Google shows no terminating quote, I suspect the full word may not be just _stakehold_.  #25 is another quote from the guide to Pern (the land where Anne McCaffrey's Dragonriders series takes place) so it could be that Ms. McCaffrey is misusing _stakehold_ or that she has defined it as an _actual thing_ in her world.

Comment: Even google asks, did you mean stakeholder?

Comment: hold -> own, usually own debt of. I happen to know because Death Valley Scotty.

Comment: Here are my thoughts regarding your answer. In order to conclude that *stakehold* is not an acceptable word, it is not enough to say that the etymology of *stakeholder* does not **logically** support back-formation to *stakehold*. After all, there are plenty of accepted words in the English language that were formed through **faulty** back-formation (e.g. [*choate*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/choate#etymonline_v_28059), [*pea*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pea#etymonline_v_10207), ...).

Comment: Nor is faulty back-formation the only way *stakehold* might have arisen. Thanks to your answer, we see that it could also be sort of an [**eggcorn**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eggcorn), sort of a blend of *stakeholder* and *stronghold* (this would be somewhat similar to how [*flustrated*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flustrated) arose from *fluster* + *-ated*, by [mimicking *frustrated*)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flustrated).

Comment: In general, in order to decide whether a new word is an acceptable word in English, its etymology, no matter how illogical or silly, cannot be the decisive factor. This is why I don't think your answer, which is ultimately about etymology, can be sufficient to establish that *stakehold* is not acceptable English. This is so even if you (and most others who contributed to this page) may well ultimately be correct in saying that it is not.

Comment: Having said that, your answer was certainly very interesting and useful, and I certainly upvoted it, even if I haven't (yet) accepted it.

Comment: I see your point, but I think that common yet incorrect usage does not a word make.  If it did, we would seen ***supposably***, ***irregardless***, and many other "words" added to dictionaries long ago.  I rue the day that ***bigly*** makes it into the OED.  I will note, however, that I am a strong supporter of adding ***zizzors*** to the dictionary simply because it's far better a word than ***scissors***.  And although we still say ***beppis*** (breakfast), ***cajamas*** (pajamas), and such around our house, they aren't actual words (nor should they be.)

Comment: Um... *irregardless*, did you say? Yes, it is flagged as 'nonstandard', but it's right there in [*M-W*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irregardless),  [*Oxford*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/irregardless), [*Am. Herit.*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=irregardless), [*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/irregardless), [*Macmillan*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/irregardless), [*Cambridge*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/irregardless)... and, yes, indeed even in the *OED*.

Comment: But even if it weren't... you say 'common yet incorrect usage'. Why, exactly, do you say that? Yes; on the one hand, clearly there is such a thing as a 'common error' (e.g. confusing *accept* with *except*, *affect*  with *effect*, etc.). But on the other hand, it is also clear that once a usage becomes widespread enough, that trumps all other considerations and the purist must throw in the towel. And, finally, it is clear that the boundary between these two cases cannot be anything but vague.

Comment: Still, in any specific example, such as here with *stakehold*, every speaker can be asked why he or she decided that a particular expression is a widespread mistake rather than a newly acceptable usage (or vice versa). So, again: why do you say *stakehold* is a mistake (given that illogical etymology is not a decisive factor)?

Comment: It might be of interest to consider this passage: *Take, for instance, the word "scientist." It was originally suggested by Whewell in 1840; but it first came into common use in America, and was received in England at the point of the bayonet. Huxley and other "scientists" disowned it, and only a few years ago the Daily News denounced it as "an ignoble Americanism," a "cheap and vulgar product of transatlantic slang."*

Comment: *But "scientist" is undoubtedly holding its own, and will soon be as generally accepted as "retrograde," "reciprocal," "spurious," and "strenuous," against which Ben Jonson, in his day, so—strenuously protested.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=bM8hAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq=words+that+purists+objected+to&source=bl&ots=U7uX6GzgCM&sig=-Pid3rNPKXuWquBHAGW8JTGxs3U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj__OOOjbLdAhXSqFkKHSkEAUkQ6AEwCnoECFkQAQ#v=onepage&q=words%20that%20purists%20objected%20to&f=false)

Comment: The general point, of course, is that all currently accepted words started off as being 'wrong', until, somehow, they eventually became 'right' (see [this post](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/02/08/when-does-wrong-become-right/) by *Oxford Dictionary*). You say that *stakehold* hasn't made this transition to 'right', at least not yet. But how do you judge that (remembering that illogical etymology is not, in and of itself, enough to disqualify a word)?

Answer (score 6):

That doesn’t sound like standard written English to me.  The accepted word would be *stake*.

Answer (score 4):

We've got a couple of good answers on where it came from, but your main question appears to be "Is **stakehold** an acceptable word?"

It depends on your audience really. When I saw the title of your question I thought "that's not a word is it? Does he mean **stakeholding**?", and then I read your many many examples and went "of course it's a word, it turns out it only looks weird to me without the indefinite article before it. I wonder why it's not in dictionaries". Then I read the answers and realised why not! I also realised that "stakeholding" isn't in most dictionaries either...

English as a language is fluid. New words are coined, and become popular, all the time. That the etymology of "stakehold" means it shouldn't really be used doesn't matter. The etymology of "awful" is "something that is so astounding it fills you full of awe", yet we still use it to mean "really, really bad" and no one minds.

So, in speech and informal writing I think it'd be fine to use. Your research has pulled up plenty of examples to show that it isn't unusual, and it's easily understood. But for formal writing you may want to steer away from it still, given that plenty of wordy people on here don't recognise it as a word. Yet.

Comment: New words are coined and some things are plain silly. To hold a stake, to have a stake doesn't end up as stakehold.

Comment: While the other answers are all useful, yours is the only one that really engages with what I was trying to ask! Unfortunately I don't think I can accept it, for the simple reason that it turned out to be what I suspected any such answer would have to be: (mostly) a personal opinion. The fault is not yours, but mine; this is why I said that, in this instance, I actually welcome personal opinions as answers, and which is why  I feared my question might ultimately be off topic. But it looks like this time around, the site mods will let me get away with it... :)

Answer (score 2):

The construction you are wondering about does exist with *freehold[er]*, describing a title of ownership of land or the "real estate", respectively the title holder. *freehold* probably exists because the "real estate" (the title, later land proper) is more substantial than an abstract "stake". A similar situation exists with *leasehold[er]* or *household[er].* Last not least *hold[er]* proper (*hold* in the sense of a stronghold, grip or custody) is an example.<sup>1</sup> That may be the reason why "stakehold" does not sound absurdly wrong.

But to express the occupation of a *stakeholder* one would just split the term into the noun and the verb it is composed of.<sup>2</sup>

That's the case with many words describing a predicate/object relationship:

- cabdriver: he's driving his cab, not  <strike>has or does a cabdrive</strike> tonight;
- caregiver
- firefighter (a [firefight](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/firefight) exists but is something different)
- toolmaker

etc.

But this is not true for all such words. Sometimes the meaning of the split phrase isn't just right (zookeeper as opposed to beekeeper). If one side is not a common word on its own they cannot be split that way (geographer).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>One should think that similar *-keep[er]* constructions exist but apparently *keep[er]* proper is the only one (there is e.g. no <s>beekeep</s>, and *barkeep* is just colloquial for *barkeeper*).</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>In German it is possible — if bad style especially in stilted academic language  — to construct a compound equivalent to "stakehold" and combine it with an unspecific verb like *machen*, *haben* oder *sein*: *er machte eine Lautäußerung* (he uttered a sound) *er nahm eine Beweisaufnahme vor* (he collected evidence) etc.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

TL:DR; No. What stakeholders have are called "stakes."

According to [google, the definition of stakeholder in this case is:](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+stake)

> a person with an interest or concern in something, especially a business.

According to the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stake), the definition of stakes is:

> a share in something, esp. a financial share in a business, or an emotional investment in something:

So stakeholders hold stakes. It's used in a sentence as follows:

> The stakeholders felt the high stakes were acceptable.
>   The shareholders agreed to stake the company's future in building Android applications and move away from Linux.